# iso I want to give routes for moving pages in this code, but when I enter the code, an error occurs. how to give routes in this code?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

```
Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 64,
            width: 64,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
                blurRadius: 3,
                spreadRadius: 4
              )

            ]
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,),
          Text("Critani")
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. please fix the code snippet and explain in more detail what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Navigator API (Navigator.pushNamed or Navigator.push). You declare the routes in MaterialApp like this:

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/fullText': (BuildContext context) => FullText(),
        '/facts': (BuildContext context) => Facts(),
      },
```

Then you can use it with onTap for example:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/facts),
```

I hope this was useful, feel free to ask questions if this is unclear!